# How do I reformat a list into integers from an API request?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I'm trying to strip out donation amounts from an API and have managed to get a response that looks like this:

```
[{'nameValuePair': [{'name': 'Donor Note'},
                    {'name': 'Donation ID', 'value': '1234'},
                    {'name': 'Full Name (F)', 'value': 'John X '},
                    {'name': 'Donation Status', 'value': 'SUCCEED'},
                    {'name': 'Donation Date', 'value': '2020-03-06'},
                    {'name': 'Donation Amount', 'value': '50.00'},
                    {'name': 'Account ID', 'value': '1235'}]},
 {'nameValuePair': [{'name': 'Donor Note'},
                    {'name': 'Donation ID', 'value': '1236'},
                    {'name': 'Full Name (F)', 'value': 'Jane X '},
                    {'name': 'Donation Status', 'value': 'SUCCEED'},
                    {'name': 'Donation Date', 'value': '2020-03-06'},
                    {'name': 'Donation Amount', 'value': '500.00'},
                    {'name': 'Account ID', 'value': '1237'}]},
]
```

and so far I have been able to get the 5th value of each dictionary with the below code where the variable donorNames is the above response:

```
donations = []
for d in donorNames:
    for k,v in d.items():
        for r in v:
            # The below v[5] retrives 5th value of the key which equals amount
            # print(v[5])
            donations.append(v[5])

for d in donations:
    for k,v in d.items():
        pprint.pprint(v)
```

So at this point, "v" is just the donation amount and the value. I want to get this into a list of integers, but I'm not even sure that what I have above is efficient and makes sense. When I print v I get a list of items like this:

`'Donation Amount'
'50.00'
'Donation Amount'
'500.00'`

So what do I need to do in order to clean this up and strip everything except for the value amount? My brain is starting to melt after spending so much time on these things and I'm getting tunnel vision. Do I need to show more of my above code for any extra context? Thank you to anyone who can provide some insight.

Comment: Are you after something like: `[float(d['value']) for dct in your_data for d in dct['nameValuePair'] if d['name'] == 'Donation Amount']` (untested)

Comment: @JonClements excellent and confirmed to work list comprehnsion. hopefully you get to post it as an answer

Comment: Sorry Jon, but I think that your response is above my current knowledge level. I will do some research to interpret this and how to incorporate it into my code